# Python script does get executed via SSH, but not on RPI itself

Tags: python, import, module

I created a GPS Script on my raspberry pi. It imports a couple of modules.
When I connect to the RPI via Visual Studio Code SSH, and execute: sudo python3 gpsd.py, the script starts. But when I try the exact same command on the local machine, I get a ModuleNotFound on the GPS and Alive_progress modules. Does anyone know what could be going wrong here?

```
from gps import *
from time import *
import time
import threading
import sys
from alive_progress import alive_bar
from datetime import datetime, date
import csv
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
import subprocess
import sys
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have all these modules installed in your local I think

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).